# Метод sort() некорректно отрабатывает в google chrome при сравнении чисел из двух массивов

Tags: javascript, сортировка, google-chrome

Всем привет!

Я только начинающий и сейчас делаю работу для портфолио, так что, пожалуйста, если что не судите строго)

Собственно, задача заключается в следующем: нужно сделать сортировку товаров по якобы дате их добавления и сделать это только из числа товаров, уже отсортированных по категориям.

Саму дату я прописал каждому товару в атрибуте data-time в виде "год-месяц-число".

Пример:

```
<div class="products__item jsFilterItem" data-time="2011-05-17" data-cat="автомодели">
    <div class="products__header">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="img" src="assets/img/products/product1.png" alt="Игрушка"/>
        </a>
        <div class="products__price">
            <span class="jsPrice" data-price="18480">18 480</span> р.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="products__footer">
        <a class="products__link" href="#">CYCLONE D4 WORLD CHAMPIONSHIP EDITION KIT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Решение этой задачи я попробовал сделать с помощью метода sort(), получив у каждого товара из сравниваемой пары значение атрибута data-time, разбив его на массив, преобразовав каждый элемент массива в число и осуществив сравнение.

Вот сам скрипт:

```
function filterDate() {
    var productsSortedOnCategories = [];
    var productsLength = products.length;
    for( var i = 0; i < productsLength; i++ ) {
        if( !$(products[i]).hasClass('hide') ) {
            productsSortedOnCategories.push(products[i]);
            $(products[i]).remove();
        }
    }

    var productsDateArray = [].slice.call(productsSortedOnCategories); // Копирование продуктов в настоящий массив.

    if( $('.jsFilterDate').hasClass('sorted') ) {
        sortProductsDateDescending();
    } else {
        sortProductsDateAscending();
    } 

    function sortProductsDateAscending() {
        productsDateArray.sort(function( a, b ) {
            var firstProductAttrValueInArray = $(a).data('time').split('-');
            var fDateValueNumbType = [];
            for( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
                fDateValueNumbType.push(Number(firstProductAttrValueInArray[i]));
            }

            var secProductAttrValueInArray = $(b).data('time').split('-');
            var sDateValueNumbType = [];
            for( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
                sDateValueNumbType.push(Number(secProductAttrValueInArray[i]));
            }

            if( fDateValueNumbType[0] - sDateValueNumbType[0]  ) {
                return 1;
            } else if( fDateValueNumbType[1] - sDateValueNumbType[1] ) {
                return 1;
            } else if( fDateValueNumbType[2] - sDateValueNumbType[2] ) {
                return 1;
            }
        });

        $(productsContainer).append(productsDateArray);
    }
}
```

В mozilla firefox все срабатывает как нужно. Но в хроме и опере нет.

В интернете увидел, что в большинстве случаев проблема возникает, когда сравнение на самом деле происходит между строками, а не числами. Но я этот момент проверил, элементы массивов все-таки становится числами после преобразования.

Может быть знаете как решить проблему? Пожалуйста, подскажите.

Comment: Ошибка в условиях `if( fDateValueNumbType[0] - sDateValueNumbType[0]  )` - оно работает не так, как вы ожидаете :) И еще, колбек в sort должен возвращать 1, 0, -1. А у вас только 1 возвращает.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, ваш ответ помог. Большое вам спасибо!

Comment: Если вы решили вашу проблему, можете опубликовать ответ. Возможно, кому-то в будущем он поможет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил код таким образом, как и посоветовал @Stepan Kasyanenko: изменил условия и дописал возвращение -1 и 0.

В таком виде метод sort() заработал корректно:

```
if( fDateValueNumbType[0] < sDateValueNumbType[0] ) return -1;
if( fDateValueNumbType[0] > sDateValueNumbType[0] ) return 1;
if( fDateValueNumbType[0] == sDateValueNumbType[0] ) {
   if( fDateValueNumbType[1] < sDateValueNumbType[1] ) return -1;
   if( fDateValueNumbType[1] > sDateValueNumbType[1] ) return 1;
   if( fDateValueNumbType[1] == sDateValueNumbType[1] ) {
       if( fDateValueNumbType[2] < sDateValueNumbType[2] ) return -1;
       if( fDateValueNumbType[2] > sDateValueNumbType[2] ) return 1;
       if( fDateValueNumbType[2] == sDateValueNumbType[2] ) {
           return 0;
       }
   }
}
```